# How to cache entire page in JavaScript that should support in all browsers

Tags: javascript

I have a page with some text boxes and I given value for all text boxes and I have a navigate button  while clicking that it navigates to another page and I have back button in the navigated page while clicking that it returns to previous page  but values got cleared.is there any solution to cache entire page using browser cacheing that should support in all browsers.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is how the browser behaves, in case like this you may need serverside code engagement. You may not need a client side caching. Though webstore and cookies are the ways to go for it for client side. On a small application its okay , but given larger application you would need some coding practices or even choose a framework to do it, otherwise your code becomes a maintenance nightmare

Comment: I need some client side level cacheing

Comment: For small app / demo app, testing, cookies is the ways to go without worrying too much on browser compatibility.Note I would still suggest follow the serverside that is how the web is coded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770185/whats-the-best-way-use-caching-data-in-js-on-client-side could also help you a little

Comment: thanku.is there any default browser cacheing?