# How to implement cache on a simple website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, frontend

I have just finished building a front-end website that has couple images here and there that might slow down the first draw and ***load time***.

I have not written backend code and I want to implement caching system on the front end side. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of my assets. or implement any cache mechanism.

Comment: take a look about: ServiceWorker

Comment: if your website is available online , so check your site using gtmetrix. it can help you to finding problems and give you some caching notes...

Comment: No cache can help with the _initial_ load … the browser must load any resource _before_ it can cache it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started here - if the resources that are used in your html page are static and resource location is also static i.e. fixed URL, then your browser will take care of the caching after the 1st time the site is loaded.

You can take a look at following links -

https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c

[What's the best way use caching data in js on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770185/whats-the-best-way-use-caching-data-in-js-on-client-side)

Hope this helps. Happy coding. :)